# jQuery: JSON stopped working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

The code below just stopped working, although I haven't even touched this part of the file since last time it worked.

```
$.post(PATH_PRODUCTS_AJAX_URL, att, function(data) {
  if(data.proper)
  {
    current_step = data.step;
    $('#product_container').append('<div class="product_content">' + data.content + '</div>');
    $('#product_container .product_content:last').animate({'left' : '-=460px'}, 200, 'swing');
  }
  else
  {
    alert('Not proper.');
  }
}, 'json');
```

My debug process is as follows:

I've checked the URL and the input data - they're both fine. I use the *data.proper* variable to ensure that the data is alright; if the data isn't processed the right way, I should get the "Not proper" alert box - but now I don't. I've also tried with a random alert box outside the if statement, but nothing happens at all.

But if I remove the JSON parameter, I get the "Not proper" box. I could also see that the output data is all fine by alerting the *data* variable.

I've checked the involves files, and they're all UTF-8 encoded.

I have really no idea what I should do next. Any help appreciated.

**Edit: (example data)**

products.php:

```
$return['proper'] = true;
$return['step'] = 1;
$return['content'] = 'Hello';

$json = json_encode($return);
echo $json;
```

Response (note that this is only returned when the JSON parameter is excluded):

```
{"proper":true,"step":1,"content":"Hello"}
```

Comment: Do you get `data.proper` in your response or not? Where exactly does it fail?

Comment: Try [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Have you upgraded to jQuery 1.5 recently? I can't see anything in the docs that should cause this but to rule out the possibility

Comment: @Pekka: data.proper is returned in the output data, but isn't processed the right way by JSON. For that reason it isn't set in my example code.

Comment: @Ivarska what does the `data` that gets passed to the function look like in `console.log()`?

Comment: Maybe the JSON is broken? Can you show some example data?

Comment: @Pekka: With JSON, nothing at all. Without JSON, I get a correct JSON string (with proper = true).

Comment: @Ivarska then it's likely the JSON is broken *somehow*. Any example data? What happens if you extend the call to `.ajax()` and include an `error` callback?

Comment: @Ivarska the data looks fine. No white space or mysterious characters around it? Also are you sending a `header("content-type: application/json")`?

Comment: @Pekka: No, I don't. The code worked fine before anyway. I tried to add the header when this problem occured, but there was no difference.

Comment: @Ivarska Weird. There must be *some* reason why it fails to parse the JSON... I don't know where to get the exact parsing error from, though, not sure whether it gets logged at all

Comment: @Pekka: I could give you an address to my server, if that'd help. I've coded in english, but the site itself is in Swedish.

Comment: @Ivarska yeah, why not, maybe I can see something. Point me to a page where the request is made, I'll take a look

Comment: @Ivarska it looks like there is an invisible character in front of the JSON, you can see it if you copy&paste the whole thing and insert it into http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Confirmed in Firefox as well. Maybe a BOM issue?

Comment: @Pekka: "syntax error, unexpected TINVALID at line 1", is that what you mean? Can't see why that'd be an invalid character.

Comment: @Ivarska look at the source code [here](http://80.217.226.9/rostfritt2/post/products_new.php?current_step=0&product_id=4&product_model=DBL&product_title=Arbetsb%C3%A4nk%20med%20underhylla), the first character - I don't know what it is, but it shouldn't be there and comes from the server end. Any white space in the PHP script or as said, a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) maybe?

Comment: @Pekka: Sorry, but I don't think I see that character. It seems like BOM was activated, though. I've Resaved with NO BOM now, but seems like it still doesn't work. Feels like it's a very small, stupid issue which causes this problem. I really appreciate the time you give my problem.

Comment: @Ivarska Google Chrome should show the invisible character in the source code view, maybe other browsers swallow it. It's now showing PHP warnings in the response though, maybe it works after removing those

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, now I see the character in Chrome - it's like an apostrophe or something. Now I've at least got something to proceed from, thanks for that.

Comment: @Ivarska no problem. I think that character is just a placeholder, though... Fix the PHP errors first and see whether it works then, my guess is it was the BOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try changing from the shorthand `.post()` to an `.ajax()` call to give you access to show the error:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: PATH_PRODUCTS_AJAX_URL,
    data: att,            
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.proper) {
            current_step = data.step;
            $('#product_container').append('<div class="product_content">' + data.content + '</div>');
            $('#product_container .product_content:last').animate({'left': '-=460px'}, 200, 'swing');
        }
        else {
            alert('Not proper.');
        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Response text: "+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        alert("Status returned: "+textStatus);
        alert("Error thrown: "+errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know how, but when I try your code it works as it should. Really weird. Well, thank you!

Comment: Hmm, that is weird - it should basically be the same call with access to the extra methods! Still glad it has helped solve the problem. It would be interesting to see what the original fault was with the `.post()` version! To find out you could switch back to `.post()` and add the following: `$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) { 
alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \n'+'error:\n' + xhr.responseText ); 
});` After a quick look it will give you access to ANY ajax errors, including the normally silent `.post()` errors.

Comment: Hah yeah, an explanation to the mysterious solution would be great. I'll test later today and return with the result!